# Access container-component's methods

Tags: angular, telerik, angular2-nativescript

I have telerik SideDrawer in a component so i can reuse it across pages by
following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752493/nativescript-make-telerik-sidedrawer-in-all-views/39755517#39755517) .. works fine.

Inside login.component.html i need to use openDrawer() method that exists in the header.component.ts
e.g:

login.component.html

```
<your-header>
    <StackLayout class="content">
        <Button text="Open!" (tap)="openDrawer()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</your-header>
```

header.component.ts

```
//~
export class HeaderComponent //~
{
    //~
    public openDrawer() {
        console.log('opened!');
        //~
    }
    //~
}
```

but i get an error: self.context.openDrawer is not a function.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37635441/4758499) it's not hard

login.component.html:

```
<your-header>
    <StackLayout class="content">
        <Button text="Open!" (tap)="_parent.openDrawer()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</your-header>
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { HeaderComponent } from "../header/header.component";
@Component({
    selector: "login",
    templateUrl: 'pages/login/login.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor() {}
    @ViewChild(HeaderComponent)
    private _parent: HeaderComponent;
}
```

The sad part is i need to add 3 lines for each component i use which is not fun.. i'd love to see a better approach.